# Problems autoscrolling page

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, autoscroll

I wrote some JavaScript that will autoscroll a Facebook page and create a spreadsheet with information from the page. The code works fine. It was a proof of concept, since I am not very proficient in JavaScript and I wasn't sure my idea would work.

The code works fine as a stand alone script. The page autoscrolls, it calls a function that does some stuff, when the page has scrolled to the bottom it stops scrolling.

Now that I got it working like it should I wanted to incorporate it into a FireFox extension I created. It doesnt have to be a FireFox extension I could easily make it a Chrome extension.

So I created a function that fires when a button is clicked. I put my scrolling code inside and I think this is the problem. The code works perfect as a stand alone script. When I put it inside of a function that only fires on button click I get an error.

Here is the code:

```
      const scroll = setInterval(function() { 
    window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight); 
    myFunction();   
    }, 2000)
```

I get this code in Chrome:
ErrorUtils caught an error: "index is not defined".

FireFox:
ErrorUtils caught an error: "assignment to undeclared variable index".

I think setInterval is conflicting with one already on the page. If the call is delayed, like it only fires on a button click it conflicts.

Any suggestions on a work around or code that will work?

Comment: Please try to reproduce the error in a code snippet (e.g. Codepen, etc). So far, the error you reported seems to have no relation with the error you are reporting. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my function is included in my code, I didn’t include it here. I didn’t think it was important. It is dying when it hits setInterval